# Custom pattern matching fails with `Enum case is not a member of type`

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a custom pattern matching that lets me switch on an error and match against the error code. See an example below:

```
enum ErrorCode: Int {
  case notSoDumb
  case dumbError
}

let myError = NSError(domain: "My domain", code: ErrorCode.dumbError.rawValue, userInfo: nil)

func ~=(pattern: ErrorCode, value: NSError) -> Bool {
  return (ErrorCode(rawValue: value.code) == pattern)
}

switch myError {
case ErrorCode.notSoDumb:
  print("Not a dumb error")
case ErrorCode.dumbError:
  print("Super dumb error")
default:
  print("No matches!")
}
```

The first case in my switch statement has an error of `Enum case 'notSoDumb' is not a member of type 'NSError'`. If I replace the `ErrorCode` enum with integers (and update my custom `~=` operator to match `Int`s and `NSError`s, everything works fine.

Comment: Obviously, you will get this error, comparing `myError` which is a NSError instance with an Int should leads to such an error... Could you please try to explain what is your main purpose?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1121. First assigning to a temporary works (e.g `let notSoDumbErrorCode = ErrorCode.notSoDumb` then `case notSoDumbErrorCode:`).

Comment: @Hamish could you please explain what's the issue here? I assume that based on the mentioned switch statement it should generate such an error...

Comment: Thanks @hamish! Do you want to add this comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @AhmadF OP is defining a custom pattern match overload of `~=` in order to allow an `ErrorCode` case to match an `NSError` value (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID426). The code should really compile.

Comment: @kubi Sure thing, gimme a sec :)

Comment: Also, a more elegant solution is to wrap each case in the identity function. `func id<T>(_ x: T) -> T {
  return x
}`

Comment: @kubi Ah that is a nice workaround; hope you don't mind that I added it to my answer for complete-ness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1121) with `enum` cases in pattern matching; the compiler incorrectly assumes that it's *always* working with an [enumeration case pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID424) rather than an [expression pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID426).

Until fixed, one way to force the compiler into 'expression pattern mode' is to first bind the case a temporary:

```
let notSoDumbErrorCode = ErrorCode.notSoDumb
let dumbErrorCode = ErrorCode.dumbError

switch myError {
case notSoDumbErrorCode:
  print("Not a dumb error")
case dumbErrorCode:
  print("Super dumb error")
default:
  print("No matches!")
}
```

However this is pretty clunky. A perhaps better workaround would be to use a `struct` with static members rather than an `enum`:

```
import Foundation

struct ErrorCode : Equatable, RawRepresentable {

  let rawValue: Int

  static let notSoDumb = ErrorCode(rawValue: 0)
  static let dumbError = ErrorCode(rawValue: 1)
}

let myError = NSError(domain: "My domain",
                      code: ErrorCode.dumbError.rawValue,
                      userInfo: nil)

func ~=(pattern: ErrorCode, value: NSError) -> Bool {
  return value.code == pattern.rawValue
}

switch myError {
case ErrorCode.notSoDumb:
  print("Not a dumb error")
case ErrorCode.dumbError:
  print("Super dumb error")
default:
  print("No matches!")
}
```

This also enables you to add additional error codes via extensions later down the line (it behaves more like an open enum). Although it does remove validation from `init(rawValue:)`, which may or may not be desirable (you could always implement your own `init?(rawValue:)` though).

Or, [as you say in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060366/custom-pattern-matching-fails-with-enum-case-is-not-a-member-of-type#comment81069399_47060366), you could stick with using an `enum`, but instead use an intermediate function call when pattern matching to force the compiler into 'expression pattern mode':

```
enum ErrorCode : Int {
  case notSoDumb
  case dumbError
}

// ...

func identity<T>(_ t: T) -> T { return t }

switch myError {
case identity(ErrorCode.notSoDumb):
  print("Not a dumb error")
case identity(ErrorCode.dumbError):
  print("Super dumb error")
default:
  print("No matches!")
}
```

Comment: now, (Swift 5.4) the switch works if the enum type is omitted eg. `case .notSoDumb`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, and despite the [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1121) linked by in @Hamish [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061086/1425697) still being open, this now compiles and works:

```
import Foundation
enum ErrorCode: Int {
    case notSoDumb
    case dumbError
}

let myError = NSError(domain: "My domain", code: ErrorCode.dumbError.rawValue, userInfo: nil)

func ~=(pattern: ErrorCode, value: NSError) -> Bool {
    return (ErrorCode(rawValue: value.code) == pattern)
}

switch myError {
case .notSoDumb:
    print("Not a dumb error")
case .dumbError:
    print("Super dumb error") // "Super dumb error\n"
default:
    print("No matches!")
}
```

My best guess is that this is related to [SE-0287](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0287-implicit-member-chains.md)